# Trying to read and write on PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to read and write on a JSON file but I'm a bit stuck in implementing it. I'm trying to append new datas in a JSON file as I iterate on more records.

**// scripts.js**

```
var jsonFile    = '../data/data.json';
var data        = { "id": 0, "animal": "Dog" }, { "id": 1, "animal": "Cat" };

var readData    = fs.read( jsonFile );

readData = readData.push( data );

fs.write( jsonFile, readData, 'a' );
```

--

What i'm trying to achieve

**data.json**

```
[]
```

**data.json - 1st iteration**

```
[
    { "id": 0, "animal": "Dog" }, 
    { "id": 1, "animal": "Cat" }
]
```

**data.json - 2nd iteration**

```
[
    { "id": 0, "animal": "Dog" }, 
    { "id": 1, "animal": "Cat" },
    { "id": 2, "animal": "Owl" },
    { "id": 3, "animal": "Bat" }
]
```

Comment: Edit question to include output of your current code.  Also have you searched on npmjs.com under 'json' or 'json update' or 'json append' or 'json stream'? There are literally thousands of modules that can simplify this.  One is `timequerylog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `[]` in the file 'data.json' before running this.

```
const fs = require('fs-promise');

async function addRecord(jsonFile, row) {
  const json = await fs.readFile(jsonFile,'utf8');
  const rows = JSON.parse(json);
  rows.push(row);
  await fs.writeFile(jsonFile, JSON.stringify(rows));
}

async function test1() {
  const jsonFile = 'data.json';
  await addRecord(jsonFile, { "id": 0, "animal": "Dog" });
  await addRecord(jsonFile, { "id": 1, "animal": "Cat" });
}

test1().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason! I can't use fs-promise but the principle worked for me. I used Phantom's File System module and used "read" and "write" method to accomplish it.